# Avoid programming continuous 'if' statements in the same method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a basic question and new to Objective-C.

I have code like below, having lot of "if" conditions. I want to enhance this code.

I can't use 'switch-case', as it (aNode) doesn't return integer.
It returns an object pointer (CC3Node*).

Could someone please advise how can I reduce these many "if" statements and enhance this code smartly?

```
-(void) nodeSelected: (CC3Node*) aNode byTouchEvent: (uint) touchType at: (CGPoint) touchPoint {

    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: A_NODE]  )
    {
        keyid =103; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: B_NODE] )
    {
        keyid =105; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: C_NODE] )
    {
        keyid =102; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: D_NODE] )
    {
        keyid =104; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: E_NODE] )
    {
        keyid =202; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: F_NODE]  )
    {
        keyid =206; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: G_NODE]  )
    {
        keyid =203; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: H_NODE]  )
    {
        keyid =207; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: I_NODE] )
    {
        keyid =208; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: J_NODE] )
    {
        keyid =401; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: K_NODE] )
    {
        keyid =402; 
    }
    if ( aNode == [self getNodeNamed: L_NODE])
    {
        keyid =404; 
    }
```

and so on....

Comment: Shouldn't you be using else if's for everything anyway?  It would reduce execution time once compiled.  The compiler will also (assuming you switch to else if's) get the given code into something relatively nice anyway - so it's just a matter of readability for the most part.

Comment: What's the type of aNode? You could be using a `NSDictionary` or else a `NSArray` instead.

Comment: At least use `else`, or place the stuff in a `do {...} while(FALSE);` block and `break` after a "successful" `if`.

Comment: (But I'd try first using a dictionary or array.)

Comment: (Or modify CC3Node to add `keyid` to it, so you don't have to look up anything.)

Comment: What is the data type of `aNode` and what is the return type of `getNotNamed:`? You probably don't want to use `==` to compare if the two types are object pointers.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply! I am sorry, i should have explained initially a bit more. 'aNode' and '[self getNodeNamed: I_NODE]' are having the data type 'CC3Node*'. It's a Cocos3d class.

Comment: Apple's web site is offline, so I can't readily check (found some other references of suspect quality) -- Does CC3Node have a field resembling the "tag" of UIView objects?  If so, you can set that and use it for your keyid value.

Answer (score 4):

You could create a dictionary with your nodeName:keyID pairs like so:

`NSDictionary * dict = @{ @"A_NODE" : @103 , @"B_NODE" : @105 , ...}`

And instead of the above series of `if` statements just write:

`keyID = dict[aNode.name];`

Eh?

**Edit:** Assuming you have a `name` property or similar on your node object, if not just add one etc.

**Edit:** Gotcha, my first edit was meant to suggest that you subclass CC3Node and add an `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * name` or find a similar "unique_id" on CC3Node and store that in the dictionary instead of name.

Comment: I'll try, thank you! Oh, but '[self getNodeNamed: A_NODE]' returns  'CC3Node*'. It's a Cocos3d class, not NSString.

Comment: From the code you posted above, it doesn't look like A_NODE is a string. Remove the `@""` around it.

Comment: I tried but, it gives compiler error unexpected @ in program. I have lower version xcode, i think that's causing this error, Can i overcome this error using the same version of xcode?

Comment: You should update to the latest version of Xcode. `@{...}` is shorthand for defining an `NSDictionary`. It's one of the new literals. You could also do `NSdictionary * dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:...];`

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on the signature of `getNodeNamed:`, but assuming it's `NSString`, you can create a dictionary that maps node names to `keyid` in the following way:

```
NSDictionary *nodeToKey = @{
  A_NODE: @(103),
  B_NODE: @(105),
  C_NODE: @(102),
  D_NODE: @(104),
};

NSInteger keyid = 0;
for (NSString *node in nodeToKey) {
  if (aNode == [self getNodeNamed:node]) {
    keyid = [nodeToKey[node] integerValue];
    break;
  }
}

// Optional: do something if keyid wasn't found.
```

Of course, if you can avoid calling `getNodeNamed:` every time (depends on the implementation), you can use the `NSDictionary` directly to fetch the `keyid`.